# Does we see in Jmeter UI report ,at what sample it stoped when first HTTP req failed

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter to code and using cmd to run the code.
My requirement is I need to stop the execution of the request when first HTTP request fails.
For ex I have 1000 threads and if it find error in 501 thread ,I need to get at 501 sample, it started for error.
[image]

I have the Thread count as shown.
set Action as Stop test on error
And ran this in cmd and result stored as .JTL file
When I viewed that .jti in Summary tree.
I see the below output

[image]

Here I see sample count is still 1000 and error% is 7.7%.
How to find out at what sample it got the error

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, by default it shows last 500 sample results, in order to increase this number you need to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
view.results.tree.max_results=0
```

also with default [Results Save Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) it shows only a limited subset of metrics like response time, status code, status message, connect time, latency, etc.

In order to be able to see full request and response you can add the next lines to the aforementioned *user.properties* file:

```
    jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
    jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
    jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

We cannot say why your test doesn't stop without seeing the full configuration, log file and knowing the nature of the failing samplers

Comment: Thank you for the reply.When I run the code in cmd ,it stopped abruptly and I didn get the "End of run " msg and prompt symbol to enter new comments in cmd prompt.Pls let me know why it happens with above said jmx file. Is it normal working as action required is set to Stop Now.